# Short of writing a driver, is it possible to create a file in Linux with dynamic contents?

Tags: linux, file, linux-device-driver

Suppose I had the files

`a.txt`:

```
foo
```

`b.txt`:

```
bar
```

And a program whose source I don't control that reads a given file from a path, is there a path I can give it that would result in it reading

```
foo
bar
```

as if it had called `cat a.txt b.txt`?

Additionally, suppose I changed an input file as such

`b.txt`:

```
baz
```

I would like the program, should it read again, to now read

```
foo
baz
```

I'm aware I could use something like a makefile to generate such a file, but that would involve running `make` every time any of the input files changed for no other benefit.

Comment: Well, it depends on how much trouble you want to go to.  You could create `c.txt` as a pipe, and have another process `cat` both files into the pipe.  But as an every time thing?  No.

Comment: Just looked up named pipes and like you said, that doesn't seem to do what I'm after, though I guess my question could be clearer.  I'll edit it now.

Comment: Right.  I think you're hoping that, whatever is contained in a.txt and b.txt, the application could read c.txt and receive the contents of both files.  That cannot be done passively.  You need some process, somewhere, to do the combining.

Comment: How sad.  Well then, with the clarification I've just added to the question, I believe your comments serve well as an answer, should you wish to claim your sweet, sweet answer points.

Comment: [FUSE](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) ?

Comment: I grant that you could do it by using FUSE to write a file system, but that a key nominee for the "not worth the trouble" award.

Comment: FUSE does seem like _a_ way to achieve this, but subjectively I don't rank it that differently to writing a device driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're hoping that, whatever is contained in a.txt and b.txt, the application could read c.txt and receive the contents of both files. That cannot be done passively. You need some process, somewhere, to do the combining.  An active process could write to a named pipe, but that's not "permanent".